# Angular 5. How to track route change in Javascript file, or execute function in component level?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular4-router

I have global.js script file and need to launch InitSwiper() function when route changes to '/home', but can't find how to track router in script file or launch function through home.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

declare var global: any; 

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit() {
    global.initSwiper();
  }

}
```

global.js

```
$(function () {

    "use strict";
    $(window).load(function(){
        pageCalculations();
        $('#loader-wrapper').fadeOut();
        $('body').addClass('loaded');
        initSwiper();
    });
...
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using CLI, you need to include that file in `.angular-cli.json` file inside "scripts" array.

if you want to call a function from that file in  `home.component.ts` only, then you can declare as below

```
declare var global:any;
```

and then on

```
ngOnInit(){
    global.InitSwiper();
}
```

Some have suggested guards, but it's overkill if you don't need to delay or prevent the route from being loaded.

Comment: From the question, initSwipe should only be called after the route has loaded

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke, yes this should work and it's simpler than guards. It does seem that the OP doesn't need the ability to prevent the route from being loaded (or delay its loading), so this is probably the best answer.

Comment: @RRForUI Thank you very much, don't know how many more hours I would have sat.

Comment: @EimisGenčiauskas glad to hear that. Please mark it as answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 2):

If you import router in your constructor you can actually subscribe it like so:

```
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private next: Router) {
  next.events.subscribe((route) => {
    if (route instanceof NavigationEnd) {
      console.log(route.url);
    }
  });
}
```

In the example above it should print out the current route.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a service and have your router call it in the canActivate once it goes to the required route like so. This will let you handle anything before the component gets loaded

router.module.ts

```
...
import {myService} from '../services/myService.service'
export const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '/home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate:[myService]}
]
...
```

myService.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router } from '@angular/router';
@Injectable()
export class myService implements canActivate{

canActivate{
  //execute initSwiper here
  if(/*success?*/){
    return true;
   }
   else{
   //redirect?
}

constructor(
  private _router: Router) { }
```

Comment: This will fail since the way you specified the routes array does not match the schema of each route object

Comment: Derp, maybe not the best solution for this issue then. The initSwiper can live inside the canActivate then. I'll edit this guy to reflect that

Comment: Problem for me is not to find the Route in component, but to execute the function there.